# Chaquopy pass the value from java class into python function and use it

Tags: java, python, chaquopy

I am using chaquopy to pass the value from java to python file. Here is the problem I faced in the coding:

This is the java code, I have passed "Halo" to function a.

```
Python py = Python.getInstance();
PyObject pyf = py.getModule("PythonFile");
PyObject obj = pyf.callAttr("a", "Halo");
```

In here, the python code receive the data and I would like to use the data to do somethings else. But the error says the function cannot pass a null value. How can I print the word "Halo" in the python?

Pyhton code:

```
def a(words):
  return words

print(a())
```

Comment: Have u initialized chaquopy using Python.start()?? Also note that chaquopy is android sdk, so I highly doubt if it works for communication between pure java and python code.

Comment: yes, my concern is how to get the data from java and use it in python

Comment: If the `print` statement is at the top level of the module, then it'll be executed when you call `getModule`. However, the function `a` takes one argument, and the `print` statement isn't passing any, so this should give the error "missing 1 required positional argument". Is this your problem? If not, please edit your question to add the complete error message, including stack trace.